# Haskell: Print type of variable within function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, ghc, ghci

How do I print the type of a variable within a function in an .hs file?

From ghci, I can do `:type var`. How do I do something like the following:

```
sumList :: [Int] -> Int
sumList [] = 0
sumList (h:t) = traceShow (type h) $ h : sumList t
```

Which would print something like h::Int at every recursive iteration?

Comment: You can work with [**`typeOf`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html#v:typeOf) for all the types that are an instance of the `Typeable` typeclass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can work with [**`typeOf :: forall a. Typeable a => a -> TypeRep`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html#v:typeOf) for all the types that are an instance of the `Typeable` typeclass:

```
import Data.Typeable(typeOf)

sumList :: [Int] -> Int
sumList = foldr (\h -> traceShow (typeOf h) (h+)) 0
```

of course for the given `sumList` function it will always return `Int`, since that is the type of of the items in the list.

Since Haskell has full *type erasure* there is no such thing like Java's `instanceof` that can determine a reference to the type at runtime: since the compiler knows all the necessary types at compile time, the objects are not "tagged" with the corresponding type.